# Is there a performance benefit single quote vs double quote in php?

Tags: php, performance

Are there any performance benefits to using single quotes instead of double quotes in php?

In other words, would there be a performance benefit of:

```
$foo = 'Test';
```

versus

```
$foo = "Test";
```