# Assigning PHP variable to HTML radio button value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to assign a PHP variable to an html radio button value like this:

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='mydisctopic' value="($row['message'])">",($row['message']),"<br>";
```

but i keep getting the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in ...
```

Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: In your quest to quote the value of `$row['message']` you have ended the string you began to echo, so parse error. By the way, quoting is not enough; you must also use `htmlspecialchars` on the value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='mydisctopic' value='".$row['message']."'>".$row['message']."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

change the line with

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='mydisctopic' value='".$row['message']."'>".$row['message']." <br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='mydisctopic' value=\"".$row['message']."\">\"".$row['message']."\"<br>";
```

Better Method:

```
    <input type="radio" name="mydisctopic" value="<?= $row['message']; ?>">"<?= $row['message']; ?>"<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='mydisctopic' value='". $row['message'] ."'>". $row['message'] ."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `"` for HTML attributes so:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="mydisctopic" value="'.$row['message'].'">'.$row['message'].'<br>';
```

`'` is faster for interpreter

If you want to use double quotes you can do this:

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='mydisctopic' value='{$row['message']}'>{$row['message']}<br>";
```

If you want to use commas (as echo can do this)

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="mydisctopic" value="',$row['message'],'">',$row['message'],'<br>';
```