# How to add variable to value of button?

Tags: php, button

How to add value of `$num` variable to value of button ?

```
<?PHP
$num = "3";
    echo '<input id="loadmore" type="button" value="$num" style=" margin-top: 20px; " > <input id="pages" type="hidden" value="$num">';
?>
```

Comment: variables in string with single quote will not be parsed & substituted with value. In short, single quote = no variable inside; double quote = can have variable inside

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Answer (score 6):

Keep it simple, use `.` (dot) to concate variable,

```
echo '<input id="loadmore" type="button" value="'. $num .'" style=" margin-top: 20px; " > <input id="pages" type="hidden" value="'. $num .'">';
```

Also have a look at [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc),

```
echo <<<EOT
<input id="loadmore" type="button" value="$num" style=" margin-top: 20px; " > <input id="pages" type="hidden" value="$num">
EOT;
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/JoVxbIOv)**.

Answer (score 3):

try to use like this. this should work

```
<?PHP
$num = "3";

echo '<input id="loadmore" type="button" value="'.$num.'" style=" margin-top: 20px; " > <input id="pages" type="hidden" value="'.$num.'">';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to use, variables inside a string, use `"` instead of `'` to initialize the string.

```
<?PHP
    $num = "3";
    echo "<input id='loadmore' type='button' value='$num' style=' margin-top: 20px;' />     
   <input id='pages' type='hidden' value='$num' />";
?>
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
    $num = "3";
    echo '<input id="loadmore" type="button" value="'.$num.'" style=" margin-top: 20px; " > 
        <input id="pages" type="hidden" value="'.$num.'">';
?>
```

Comment: I would good if you describe correction in OP code it will help to other as well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Demo : https://eval.in/87528

**Try this:**

```
<?php

$num = "3";
    echo "<input id='loadmore' type='button' value='{$num}' style=' margin-top: 20px; ' > <input id='pages' type='hidden' value='{$num}'>";
?>
```

Output:

```
<input id='loadmore' type='button' value='3' style=' margin-top: 20px; ' > <input id='pages' type='hidden' value='3'>
```

See this for details:  http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/php-beware-of-variables-inside-strings