# selcet from mysql using php variable

Tags: php, mysql

How can I use a variable inside a mysql select from statment? like so:

```
$db = $_POST['db'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM $db..";
```

Comment: You ought to whitelist it for allowed table names.

Comment: I did, but for some reason couldn't find it couldn't find it, so I asked here.

Comment: Start [here](http://prototype.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To literally answer the question:

```
$db = $_POST['db'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$db}..";
```

OR

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$_POST['db']}..";
```

OR

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$_POST['db']."..";
```

As others have said, accepting unsanitized input from the POST is a very bad idea indeed

at the very least you should do the following

```
$db = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['db']);
```

which will atleast ensure that other commands will not be inserted such as INSERTS, UPDATES, or GRANT