# MySQL AVG function returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, average, resultset

I'm using the code below to query the database.

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM _$symbol ORDER BY date DESC;");     

$_10day = mysql_query ("SELECT AVG(close) FROM _$symbol limit 10;");
$_21day = mysql_query ("SELECT AVG(close) FROM _$symbol limit 21;");
$_50day = mysql_query ("SELECT AVG(close) FROM _$symbol limit 50;");

echo "$_10day\n";
echo "$_21day\n";
echo "$_50day\n";


mysql_query ("INSERT INTO _$symbol(_10day) VALUE ('$_10day');");

echo mysql_errno($sql) . ": " . mysql_error($sql). "\n";
```

I need to get the average of `close` from the database, and I'm using the `AVG()`function, then insert the return value into the database. The queries work in mysql however they do not work through the script. It does enter a value into the database, but it always enters `0`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT--solution found

`$get10 = mysql_query ("SELECT AVG( close ) AS CloseAverage from ( SELECT close FROM _$symbol ORDER BY date DESC limit 10 ) sub1 ;");`

`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get10);
  $_10day = $row['CloseAverage'];`

`if (!mysql_query ("UPDATE _$symbol SET _10day = $_10day, _21day = $_21day, _50day = $_50day, _100day = $_100day, _120day = $_120day, _150day = $_150day, _200day = $_200day, _240day = $_240day, _20dayVol = $_20dayVol, _50dayVol = $_50dayVol  where date = '$date';")) 
 {
        echo "Update query failed";
 }`

I was querying it incorrectly apparently it needed to be selected as a sub query, solution is above, it is working now.

Comment: where do you execute the query? you just wrote the query

Comment: PHP and yes just like that

Comment: @illcrx: He asked you where the part of execution is. You just set up a query which never gets executed in the current snipped.

Comment: Ok well I guess that is where my problem is then. how do I execute it? I have just been making sure the query works in mysql then putting it in as you see above

Comment: Hah lol. Yeah I thought you did that... ill post an example.

Comment: Use **proper** variable concatenation: `FROM _' . $symbol . ' limit` my eyes hurt from this kind of worst practice.

Comment: @DanFromGermany There is absolutely nothing wrong with writing variables directly into double quoted strings. Where did you get the idea it was?

Comment: what is the benefit/drawback of doing it the two ways? (I am still learning here) Thanks @DanFromGermany

Comment: @DanFromGermany, can you explain please, I would like to know why

Comment: @DanFromGermany In a double quoted string, no. `$string = 'string'; echo "This is a $string";` is fine. `$string = 'string'; echo 'This is a $string';` is not.

Comment: Think of more complex situations. It doesn't work using arrays, anon functions, properties,... It's not as readable, it's not clean, it's not consistent,..  Examples: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qemnfr

Comment: @DanFromGermany You put curly brackets around array and object properties and functions. eg `{$array[0]}` and `{$obj->func()}`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string

Answer (score 0):

`$_10day` is a mysql result, not a value. You can't just put a result into a query string and expect it to work.

You need to get the result data first, eg;

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($_10day)) {
     $10day = $row['AVG(close)'];
}
```

Then you can execute your insert query;

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO _$symbol (_10day) VALUES ('$10day')");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, since I should be returning an AVG from the query, would the mysql_fetch_assoc be the right way to go, from what I am seeing that is used for arrays?

$get10 = mysql_query ("SELECT AVG(close) FROM _$symbol limit 10;");


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($_10dayget) {
     $_10day = $row['AVG(close)'];'}


mysql_query ("INSERT INTO _$symbol(_10day) VALUE ('$_10day');");



this is what I have now. thanks @worldofju

Comment: As you only have one value returned, give `mysql_fetch_array` a go. The data would be saved in `$row[0]`.

Comment: You might also need to make your AVG select more explicit. Try `SELECT AVG(close) AS CloseAverage FROM _$symbol limit 10`.

Comment: Ok please forgive me but how do I implement that? '$10day = $row[0];'

Comment: Yes `$10day = $row[0];`

Comment: I cant seem to get anything to work! I have been working on this issue for too too long, I know its simple but I dont know what Im doing wrong, Im sure your answer is correct I must have something else wrong and/or implementing it wrong. Also I have 2 kids Im watching at home so past several hours havent been spent doing anything on the project, I will definitely let you know when I get it working

Comment: No worries. Take note of the `SELECT` statement a few comments above. This might solve your problems.

Comment: So I tried the AS CloseAverage statement is that going to save that as a variable in mysql for me without having to go through all that PHP?

Comment: No, it just returns the average with the name `CloseAverage` in the result set. So you could access it with `$row['CloseAverage']` when using `mysql_fetch_assoc` but still `$row[0]` when using `mysql_fetch_array` (assuming it's the first column asked for).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62213/discussion-between-worldofjr-and-illcrx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to manage multiple result-rows:

```
function connect()
{
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die("your error msg");
    mysql_select_db("database_name");
    return $db;
}

$db = connect();

$query = "SELECT value1 FROM my_table";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    // This one will loop through the data in your output//
    $outputValue = $row['value1'];

}
```

**For inserting data:**

```
// Continued from the state above //
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1) VALUES (value1)";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Actually, he did execute them, but he didn't fetch the result.