# How to do an href link in a selected $variable

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with a problem I'm doing.

It's simple.

I have this code.

```
while ($ row = mysql_fetch_array ($ resultadosql))
{

  echo ("<tr> <td>" $ row ["id"] "</ td>"..);
  echo ("<td> <a href='themedisplay.php?id=" $row["id"] "'> edit </a> </ td>..");
```

the second is a link in another column to another window to edit the inserted data.

What I want to change the link "edit" to variable id, in other words to put the last echo inside this.

```
echo ("<tr> <td>" $ row ["id"] "</ td>"..);
```

That the id showed is the link to the editing window.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: To make the link open a new window (or tab), use the attribute target="_blank".

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

The code may have more errors  (im assuming your post code formatting is alittle off) but here corrects the visible one:

Change these snippets to:

```
"<tr> <td>" . $row["id"] . "</ td>"

"<td> <a href='themedisplay.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'> edit </a></td>"
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. Let's see, i have a table with several columns, one that shows the variable $id , more and another it's just a link to a new window to edit the content of that selected. What i want  to do is that just by clicking at the id's i can go to that edit window.

Comment: @dax i think that you maybe right, try editing your question so its a little clearer