# variable in SQL INSERT

Tags: sql

I'm new in SQL, I would like to know how I can have this code working. Because it doesn't understand that `$lala` and `$lolo` are variable.

```
$lolo = "ahha";
$lala = "2";
$sql = "INSERT INTO organisation (id_orga, nom) VALUES ";
$sqll = '($lala, $lolo)';

$resultat = $conn->query($sql.$sqll);
```

so I tried:

```
$lolo = "ahha";
$lala = "2";
$sql = "INSERT INTO organisation (id_orga, nom) VALUES ";
$sqll = '('.$lala.','. $lolo.')';

$resultat = $conn->query($sql.$sqll);
```

But both code don't `INSERT` in my `BDD` and also give no error.

Comment: even at the start, always use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Also which DBMS are you using? And what programming language is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP the varibles are declared like so:

```
$lala = "ahah";
```

When you need to echo or print them you can do the string concatenation like
`echo 'this is my' . $lala;` OR `echo "this is my $lala";`

This happens because the double quotes allow you to insert the variable without the need to concatenate.
So, in your case:

```
$sqll = '('.$lala.','. $lolo.')';
```

is **correct** and is the same as:

```
$sqll = "($lala, $lolo)";
```

---

With the single quotes     `$sqll = '($lala, $lolo)';` wouldn't work as it would output `($lala, $lolo)` and not `(2, ahaha)`

---

**Note**: take a look at [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which is a better alternative to mysql security-wise

Comment: Well thanks for your great answer but i figure it out here is the working code:`$lolo = "ahha";
        $lala = "2";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO organisation (id_orga, nom) VALUES ";
        $sqll = "('".$lala."','". $lolo."')";

        $resultat = $conn->query($sql.$sqll);
        echo $sql.$sqll;`

Comment: yes you also need the single quotes for inserting strings in db and writing them in your insert statement

Comment: please also select an answer and upvote the ones that helped you. thnx

Answer (score 1):

try with double quotes

```
$sqll = "($lala, $lolo)";
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string