# Cannot insert WHERE statement with a variable in php query

Tags: php

```
    <?php

    // Working SELECT query.
    $db = new SQLite3('casino.db');

    // This works great and returns only name = bergpau !!!
    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM employe WHERE username="bergpau"');
   while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) 
         print  $row['nom'] . "<BR>";

   // This DOES NOT WORK AT ALL, returns no values !!! HELP !!!
   $astring = "bergpau";
   $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM employe WHERE username=$astring');
   while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) 
        print  $row['nom'] . "<BR>";

   ?>
```

Opening database, ok
return no value since it cannot validate string in WHERE clause

Comment: Did you check for errors? The second SELECT looks like it would result in a mysql error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string this will be of interest to you

Answer (score 1):

Strings, in SQL (and PHP), need to be quoted like you did in your first query (`username="bergpau"`). This also could open you to SQL injections; you should use parameterized queries.

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM employe WHERE username='{$astring}'");
```

Also variables in single quotes aren't processed by PHP.

> Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

-http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Alternatively you could pass the quotes in the assignment (note the double quotes are for the encapsulation in PHP, the single quotes are stored in the value of `$astring`):

```
$astring = "'bergpau'";
```

then you'd just need to concatenate the variable.

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM employe WHERE username=' . $astring);
```