# PHP variable inside curl_init URL

Tags: php, curl

I use the curl function to get information from a certain webpage. In the following code the URL is static:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://00.00.0.00/route/v1/driving/12.869446,54.990799;12.045227,54.044362?overview=full&steps=true'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 5000);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 5000); 
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

But the part's lat lng (12.869446,54.990799) in the URL need to be php variables like: `$lng`, `$lat`.

My first solution doesn't work:

```
$lat = '54.990799';
$lng = '54.990799'; 
$curl = curl_init('http://00.00.0.00/route/v1/driving/$lng,$lat;12.045227,54.044362?overview=full&steps=true');
```

My second solution with " doesn't work either:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://00.00.0.00/route/v1/driving/"$lng","$lat";12.045227,54.044362?overview=full&steps=true');
```

Can anyone help me with the best solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Comment: Did you really did any search before asking? Look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string) question. All you need is concatenate your variable with the string, and there is many ways doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Variables can be used inside "".

```
 $curl = curl_init("http://00.00.0.00/route/v1/driving/{$lng},{$lat};12.045227,54.044362?overview=full&steps=true");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can embed variables in a string this way:

```
$curl = curl_init("http://00.00.0.00/route/v1/driving/$lng,$lat;12.045227,54.044362?overview=full&steps=true");
```

Or for better readability also add `{}` around variables (IDE can often make a proper code highlighting to such syntax):

```
$curl = curl_init("http://00.00.0.00/route/v1/driving/{$lng},{$lat};12.045227,54.044362?overview=full&steps=true");
```

Or alternatively you can concatenate strings with variables.

```
$curl = curl_init('http://00.00.0.00/route/v1/driving/' . $lng . ',' . $lat . ';12.045227,54.044362?overview=full&steps=true');
```