# Assign different names to text box using loop php

Tags: php, database, loops, textbox

how to assign different names to text box using loop? I've tried some coding but it doesn't catch the value I entered.

Sorry for my lack coding skills. Thank you in advance.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo $row["criteria_name"];
        echo '<input name="$criteria_name" type="textbox"/> <br/><br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try this:

echo '<input name="'.$criteria_name.'" type="textbox"/> <br/><br/>';

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<input name="'.$row["criteria_name"].'" type="textbox"/> <br/><br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use variables inside of string while using **double quotes**

This **will** work:

```
echo "Hello world $variable";
```

While this will **not**:

```
echo 'Hello world $variable';
```

I can see, however, that it may be an issue because there's double quotes in the HTML, this leaves you with a few options.

**Option 1**

Use double quotes to encase the string, and then escape the existing double quotes:

```
echo "<input name=\"$criteria_name\" type=\"textbox\"/> <br/><br/>";
```

**Option 2**

Concatenate the strings:

```
echo '<input name="' . $row['criteria_name'] . '" type="textbox"/> <br/><br/>';
```

**Option 3**

Use the alternative syntax for the control structures, and use raw HTML:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0):
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
    ?>
        <?= $row["criteria_name"]; ?>
        <input name="<?= $criteria_name; ?>" type="textbox"/><br/><br/>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to name $row['criteria_name'] as input field name

```
    echo '<input name="'.$row['criteria_name'].'" type="textbox"/> <br/><br/>';
```

Please check the options provided by the accepted answer on how to concatenate variable within a string in the below post 
[PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)