# How to echo the statement

Tags: php

How to echo the statement in if condition.

Please refer code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('<?php echo $web ?>index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Please correct this

```
$user_home->redirect('<?php echo $web ?>index.php');
```

I want to echo **$web**.

Comment: What value is store in `$web` variable ?

Comment: you should be getting a parse error with this.l

Answer (score 3):

In PHP code you didn't need to echo the variable. You are trying to concatenate a string here using the value in the $web variable. So you can use `.` to join the strings.

```
 $user_home->redirect($web.'index.php');
```

Comment: thnx for the answer, it helped me out

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect($web.'index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

You may also refer [PHP Concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Comment: thnx for the answer, it helped me out