# Inserting a PHP variable into Eloquent WhereRaw SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How would you go about inserting a php variable $date into an eloquent whereRaw? The following will work with curDate() but can't pass a variable through.

```
$ex = User::whereRaw('month({$date}) = month(dob) and day($date) = day(dob)')->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whether the value of date will decided by user or php script but you always have to prepare raw statement by PDO,

Your raw statement will look like (safe)

```
$ex = User::whereRaw('month(?) = month(dob) and day(?) = day(dob)')->setBindings([$date, $date])->get();
```

Or

```
$ex = User::whereRaw("month($date) = month(dob) and day($date) = day(dob)")->get();
```

Also you have to look into this answer, [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605970/1578380)

Answer (score 0):

You may try by replacing `'` with `"`

```
$ex = User::whereRaw("month({$date}) = month(dob) and day($date) = day(dob)")->get();
```

Comment: No luck, possible '$date' is in the wrong format? It's coming through from an AJAX request to the controller, outputting to the log give a date in the format '2017-06-29', but does not seem to work when inserting the variable into the raw sql, though copying and pasting the value directly into the sql '$bu = User::whereRaw("month('2017-06-29') = month(dob) and day('2017-06-29') = day(dob)")->get();' does work