# Date variable month not working

Tags: php

How can i put a variable month in date function ?

```
$nbrmonth = 6;

$onemonth = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime()) . " + 1 month")); //work
$variabledate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime()) . " + '.$nbrmonth.' month")); // not working
```

Comment: Try `$variabledate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime()) . ' + ' . $nbrmonth . ' month'));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
$variabledate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime()) . " + ".$nbrmonth." month")); //  working
```

Try out this.

This is the output:

```
2018-05-28 16:00:11
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$variabledate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime()) .' + ' 
 .$nbrmonth .' month'));
```