# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE What am i doing wrong_

Tags: php, mysql

When i try to post my data by PHP into SQL, I get an error message on the webpage:

> Error: insert INTO mydata ( uke, man1, tir1, colman1, coltir1 ) VALUES ( '7', '','','','') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE man1 = , tir1 = , colman1 = , coltir1 = 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' tir1 =  ' at line 14

```
$uke = $_POST[uke];
$man1 = $_POST[man1];
$tir1 = $_POST[tir1];
$colman1 = $_POST[colman1];
$coltir1 = $_POST[coltir1];



  $sql = "insert INTO mydata  ( uke,  
  man1, tir1, 
  colman1, coltir1)
  VALUES 
  ( 
  '$uke',
  '$man1','$tir1',
  '$colman1','$coltir1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
man1 = $man1,
tir1 = $tir1,
colman1 = $colman1,
coltir1 = $coltir1";
```

SQL is:

```
uke int(11) No  Primary NULL    
timer   float(255,2)    Yes None    NULL    
man1    decimal(20,2)   Yes None    NULL    
tir1    decimal(20,2)   Yes None    NULL    
colman1 varchar(255)    Yes None    NULL
coltir1 varchar(255)    Yes None    NULL
```

Can anyone give me a hint (or tell me) where i have the error?

Comment: `man1 = ` Don't you think there should be value after `=`?

Comment: Is this that you want? `UPDATE man1 = '', tir1 = '', colman1 = '', coltir1 = ''`

Comment: and this query has sql injection bug you must use parameters.

Comment: @JohnWoo I think it is even `man1 = '$man1'` and so on

Comment: Please do not include "SOLVED" in a Question title, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be updated like this.

```
$sql = "insert INTO mydata  ( uke,  man1, tir1, colman1, coltir1)
                  VALUES ( '$uke','$man1','$tir1', '$colman1','$coltir1')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                man1 = '$man1',
                tir1 = '$tir1',
                colman1 = '$colman1',
                coltir1 = '$coltir1'";
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I have to read more about sql injecting i see. :-)

Comment: Glad that helpd! :) And mark the answer as the accepted answer. So, others can easily find the correct answer!

Comment: What is the difrence between your and Gagan Upadhyay answer?

Comment: That also should work. He's just contacting the variables to the query string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string

Answer (score 1):

```
$uke = (isset($_POST[uke])) ? $_POST[uke] : '';
$man1 = (isset($_POST[man1])) ? $_POST[man1] : '';
$tir1 = (isset($_POST[tir1])) ? $_POST[tir1] : '';
$colman1 = (isset($_POST[colman1])) ? $_POST[colman1] : '';
$coltir1 = isset($_POST[coltir1])) ? $_POST[coltir1] : '';

$sql = "INSERT INTO mydata  ( uke, man1, tir1, colman1, coltir1)
    VALUES ( '$uke', '$man1','$tir1', '$colman1','$coltir1')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   man1 = '" .  $man1 . "',
   tir1 = '" . $tir1 . "',
   colman1 = '" . $colman1. "',
   coltir1 = '" . $coltir1 . "'";
```

Try this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this inject proofing?

Comment: @Bergum No, it is not.