# Replace Instagram URL to Embed

Tags: php, regex, curl, instagram, embed

How to replace Instagram URLs from a text in embed format with regex?

```
//Input
$text = 'There is https://www.instagram.com/p/Bes0orNjOIa/?taken-by=kendalljenner and then there was https://www.instagram.com/p/BZMh9qgl8Kw/?taken-by=felix.gaebler';

//Expected output
$text = 'There is <iframe src="//www.instagram.com/p/Bes0orNjOIa/embed"></iframe> and then there was <iframe src="//www.instagram.com/p/BZMh9qgl8Kw/embed"></iframe>';
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Regex is for matching `Strings`, not replacements or something similar.

Comment: `$text = It was...` if that's your real code, would throw you an `undefined constant` warning.

Comment: This question is unclear for too many reasons.

Comment: @FelixGaebler  i want to apply the Embed mode for URLs Instagram.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sure, i know)

Comment: @MarkDidle did I get it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is for matching Strings, not replacements or something similar.
If you want to convert your text into an embed link, this is a way to go:

```
<?php
    $text = 'There is https://www.instagram.com/p/Bes0orNjOIa/?taken-by=kendalljenner and then there was https://www.instagram.com/p/BZMh9qgl8Kw/?taken-by=felix.gaebler';
    $words = explode(' ', $text);

    $output = array();  

    foreach ($words as $word) {

        if(preg_match('/^https:\/\/www\.instagram\.com\/p\/.{6,}\?/', $word)) {

            $code = explode("/", $word)[4];
            $word = '<iframe src="//www.instagram.com/p/$code/embed"></iframe>';

        } 

        array_push($output, $word);

    }

    echo implode(' ', $output);
?>
```

Output here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuKjh.png

Comment: Thank You! But how can this be applied to multiple URLs at once? For example, I have 2 references in the $text variable.

Comment: Seperated by an comma? Or better in an array?

Comment: I meant my example.
$text = 'It was ...';

Comment: so recognize the urls automatically via regex and then make them embed! :) why dont say so

Comment: Your example allows you to manipulate a single URL. Need to do this with several URLS in one variable.

Comment: filtered out of the text? Can you please peer review my edit of your question

Comment: Your example works, I fixed the error in variable and parentheses. Does your example allow you to do this with just one URL? True?

Comment: wait I will give you what you need

Comment: Yes! All is well!

Comment: @MarkDidle can you mark it as solution with the tick next to the question? Would be awesome for my karma!

Comment: Can you make a small correction for future generations?) In the variable $word have to allocate a variable $code -> .'$code'.
I dont have enought points for this action :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by allocate a variable $code -> .'$code'. ... the code variable is automatically attached to the string ;)

Comment: I mean, without this amendment, the variable will be displayed simply as $code, not any value) that is, in the source code of the page I see it:
<iframe src="//www.instagram.com/p/$CODE/embed"></iframe>

Comment: it should not.. except I got something wrong with multiple `"` and `'`... but php should add the text to the string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string