# Chunk MySQL query using REGEX

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have Mysql query

```
$query = "SELECT ticket_id, subject FROM tickets WHERE status_code = 0 GROUP BY priority ORDER BY incident_id LIMIT 5";
```

I want to convert this

```
$select = "SELECT ticket_id, subject ";
$from = "FROM tickets ";
$where = " WHERE status_code = 0 ";
$group = "GROUP BY priority";
$order = "ORDER BY incident_id";
$limit = "LIMIT 5";
```

> How can I achieve this? Is it possible to do with REGEX? Please give
>   me your instructions?

or advise me

> how to take a specific string value using REGEX?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: probably substring function will do the trick. All of your query has where, group, order and limit?

Comment: You need a SQL parser. This might seem like a candidate for a regular expression, but it's not. What about `SELECT (SELECT id FROM x) AS y LEFT JOIN ...`? It gets unbelievably complicated for all but the most trivial of queries.

Comment: at present, i would get such type of queries @tadman

Comment: Just use a SQL parser. Regular expressions are not the answer to everything.

Comment: @Siddhu Why not use this variables in string see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Comment: AT MY PRESENT SENIRAIO IT WILL NOT WORK @ZYDNAR

Comment: @Siddhu but this is not included in your question, so update it, or change. And please don't SHOUT.

Comment: Could you explain what that's good for and what the real problem is?

Comment: I want to add extra add filers later at WHERE condition, So that I'm separating the query

Comment: Once you have the code to parse _that_ statement, your next statement will have some variation that breaks your REGEXP.  My point is that this is too much of an energy sink to be worth pursuing.  (I had the same Question 15 years ago; I have yet to find a good answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a PHP Sql parser such as https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser

Go through their documentation and you will find examples of how to accomplish exactly what you requested above.
[Edit]: here's their manual page: https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser/wiki/Parser-Manual

Regular expressions solution is going to get messy quickly...