# Laravel Localization position depend on variable

Tags: laravel

I want to make standard request for laravel localization file: animals.php

which looks like:

```
<?php 
return [
    'dog' => 'dog trans',
    'cat' => 'cat trans',
    'super-mutant-spider' => 'super-mutant-spider trans',
];
```

Now when I'm accessing this, I'm simply writing:

`trans('animals.dog')` -> gives `dog trans` etc.

this is fine,

now I want to make it depend on the user variable animal:

so when `$user->animal` is 'dog' I want `dog trans` result.

so when I try: `trans('animals.$user->animal')` it will not work

How can I code it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basic string concatenating.

What you need is basically this: `trans('animals.' . $user->animal)`

You have detailed explanation on [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605965/397195)