# Select query for getting a single value is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 $sql = "SELECT temail FROM teacherusers WHERE tfullname='$teachername' limit 1";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $value = mysql_fetch_object($result);
 $teacheremail2 = $value->temail;
 echo $teacheremail2;
```

`echo $teacheremail2` returns nothing.

`$teachername` is valid and i have checked multiple times.

Comment: Not an answer, but using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless, because there is no formal logic/reasoning regarding _which_ single record you want to get back.  Add an `ORDER BY` clause so that the query makes sense.

Comment: What is your php version, and do you have display errors enabled?

Comment: how do i enable display errors ?

Comment: Version information: 4.7.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Error reporting for PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and `mysql_error()` for the query are two error checking tools for you to use. You can then update your question to contain what those errors were, if any.

Comment: I think that's likely the phpmyadmin version, not the php version

Answer (score 0):

It should be a two-dimensional array , you need 

`$value[0]->temail`

Comment: Pretty sure mysql_fetch_object returns an object.

Comment: Sorry no results

Answer (score 0):

The result of `mysql_fetch_object($result)` is an object(stdClass).

The explanation of `object(stdClass)` ican be found at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)

```
$sql = "SELECT temail FROM teacherusers WHERE tfullname='$teachername' limit 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($value = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
    $teacheremail2 = $value->temail;
    echo $teacheremail2;
    }
```

Comment: how mickmackusa ?

Answer (score -1):

First off, you'll want to run the query directly against your database to ensure that the query returns some kind of result.
Secondly, if that works, you'll want to echo $value directly to check that you are getting results back on the webpage.

Then you can check if temail is a field of $value

Comment: I ran SELECT temail FROM `teacherusers` WHERE `tfullname` = "XXX XXX"
and i got the result in the phpmyadmin

Comment: Good. So move on to the second step then

Comment: echo $value; shows nothing .
temail is the column name of the table , double checked

Comment: Try using var_dump http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php
Also, ensure that you have set an intial value for $teachername

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = "SELECT temail FROM teacherusers WHERE tfullname='$teachername' limit 1";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($value = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
    $teacheremail2 = $value->temail;
    echo $teacheremail2;
    }
```

hope this help

Comment: This should work either way because of variable interpolation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string

Comment: can you provide me the table and its data?

i'll test in my local