# Adding a constant value to a variable in a MySQL search statement (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

```
$level_sql_switch = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT course_period_id 
                                         FROM course_periods 
                                         WHERE school_id = '$campus' 
                                         AND short_name = '$level'");
$course_period_id = $level_sql_switch->fetch_assoc();
$course_period_id = $course_period_id['short_name'];
```

For Example, when the excel file is read, the variable $level stores the value "C1". I would like to return a C1-T from the database using a select statement. How would you do so while ruling out the other variants of C1 (C1-A, C1-B, C1-C, C1-T2 and etc). As you cannot simply set the short_name = '$level' or use a substring.

```
"SELECT course_period_id FROM course_periods WHERE school_id = '$campus' AND short_name = '$level'"
```

Comment: `mysqli_qeury()` is that a custom function of yours? If not; it's a typo.

Comment: *"when the short_name being read from the excel is C1"* - Excel? Your question's unclear for a few reasons here.

Comment: It is not a custom function, has it been depreciated?https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: ___Not deprecated, but you have to spell it correctly___. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: No, you wrote qeury instead of query

Comment: No its misspelled its `query` as you wrote yourself not `qeury` as it is in your code

Comment: Also "depreciated" and "deprecated" are two very different things. Check your spellings generally, I think.

Comment: Hahaha rough day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out riggsfolly actually helps alot!

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @Xenos Try to avoid w3schools whenever possible. That site contains wildly out of date material and is chock full with toxically bad advice. The [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is considerably better and the community comments help in situations where the documentation isn't entirely clear. Another good resource if you're just getting started is [PHP the Right Way](https://www.phptherightway.com).

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% made clear, but presumably `$level` won't always contain `C1`.  Assuming also that you always want to find the variant `-T` then you could simply set the parameter as

```
short_name = '$level-T'
```

In full:

```
SELECT course_period_id 
FROM course_periods 
WHERE school_id = '$campus' AND short_name = '$level-T'
```

---

It should also be noted that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL like the above.

As I said above, you can find examples of precisely how to write what you need, but a parameterised version of your query with mysqli would look like:

```
SELECT course_period_id 
FROM course_periods 
WHERE school_id = ? AND short_name = ?
```

Then elsewhere you'd assign your first parameter to be `$campus` and your second to be `"$level-T"` before passing them to the query.

Comment: Why is this concatenation even remotely necessary? PHP can interpolate like it does for `$campus`. That being said, both of these should be placeholder values.

Comment: @tadman true. Not sure why I did that. Have edited. And yes it should really be parameterised, but that's a separate topic I guess. I don't know if the values in question are taken from user input into the spreadsheet or not. It's not clear.

Comment: Getting it working *correctly* is never a separate topic. This is half a fix, and it preserves the huge SQL injection hole. Parameterizing it is easy for you, just put `?` instead and leave the rest as an exercise for the reader. You'll also need to use double-quotes on `$short_name = "$level-T"` or it won't interpolate.

Comment: Improvements much appreciated, though it's usually best to give the safe advice first. People usually latch on to the first thing that "works" and don't read the warnings.