# How would I correctly parse this PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know the PHP part of this code is wrong but I can't figure out how to write it correctly. Can someone give me a hand?

```
function add_last_nav_item($items) {
  return $items .= '<li><a class="cart-button" href="/cart">View cart (<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>)</a></li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item');
```

Comment: Hm, don't `<?php echo` from PHP

Comment: I'm not sure how to write that. I've tried already and it always crashes the site.

Comment: Don't tell us that it is wrong. Tell us what you want to achieve with this piece of code. We can then tell you what is wrong or right.

Comment: Well, currently, it crashes the site and I don't know why. I want it to not crash the site.

Comment: Crashes how? The PHP in PHP is definitely wrong. Please edit the question and tell us what you want to do here.

Comment: Yeah, the PHP in PHP is the issue I have. Not sure how to write that part correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to `<?php echo` from PHP, concatenate the value you need (`WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()`). Change to:

```
function add_last_nav_item($items) {
  return $items .= '<li><a class="cart-button" href="/cart">View cart ('. WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() .')</a></li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php