# How to print a variable in href with php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass an id in a link href and I need it to be printed in the URL, my code is:

```
echo "<a href='ville.php?id='"echo.$ville_id."> $ville_nom </a>";
```

But the id is not print in the url, could you help me with the syntax ?

Comment: `echo "<a href='ville.php?id=".$ville_id." '>". $ville_nom ."</a>";` I think there is a lot of question about this on SO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in your usage of echo and your concat was wrong.

The corrected code :

```php
echo "<a href='ville.php?id='".$ville_id."'> $ville_nom ";
```

When you used the double quote it's not necessary to concat variables to show their content. Be careful: it can be dangerous sometimes.

```php
echo "<a href='ville.php?id=$ville_id'> $ville_nom ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```php
echo "<a href='ville.php?id=" . $ville_id . "'>"
```