# Advanced URL in $html_string

Tags: php, xpath, get

Ok, so right now I've got this URL, which works perfectly:

```
$html_string = file_get_contents('https://www.123.com/' . $_GET["ticket"]);
```

What I want to do is to insert $_GET between the URL.

Here's what I mean:

```
('https://www.123.com/' . $_GET["ticket"] /url-continues-here);
```

I have tried everything, but can't find any solution how to do it without an error.

Comment: So concatenate the rest of it after the variable...

Comment: You can find examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string).

Comment: I'm new to this, could you please write a simple code? That would be awesome.

Comment: Please read through the linked question. There are multiple examples dealing with a variable being inserted between two pieces of string.

Answer (score -1):

Concatenate the 2 strings first and after that use `file_get_contents()`

```
$html_string = 'https://www.123.com/' . $_GET["ticket"] . '/url-continues-here';
file_get_content($html_string);
```

Comment: You have merely re-used the code that the question author explicitly says *works*.

Comment: The OP just has to concatenate the different parts of the url in string and  then use `file_get_content()` instead of trying to do it as the function argument

Comment: That is outright wrong. Expressions can be passed as function parameters (unless passed by reference, which isn't the case with `file_get_contents`).

Comment: I am not saying the can't be passed, I am saying that it will be clearer if he does it this way, and there is a less chance for mistake

Comment: "Clearer" is subjective and suggestions don't make suitable answers - they're better off as comments. Besides, your answer does not read as suggestion to make things clearer, it reads as though the issue was in directly passing the concatenated url.