# PHP - make a string from a variable from several different function, add strings together

Tags: php, wordpress, string, advanced-custom-fields

I need to make a PHP variable that takes `get_template_directory_uri()`, appends `/assets/images` and appends `the_sub_field('icon')` and appends the string `-colored.png` how do I do this?

The correct output needs to looks like this:

`...assets/images/icon-linkedin-colored.png`

`...assets/images/icon-facebook-colored.png`

I've confirmed the output of `<div><?php echo the_sub_field('icon') ?></div>` is correct.

The first thing I tried:

```
<?php $iconName = echo get_template_directory_uri() + '/assets/images/' + the_sub_field('icon') + '-colored.png'; ?>
```

In VS code I just get "No quick fixes available which doesn't help me.

[PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

I then tried

```
<?php $iconName = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/' . the_sub_field('icon') . '-colored.png'; ?>
```

Because I forgot you do `.` for trying strings (or string concactenation)

But the output of this is

`.../assets/images/-colored.png`

Why is it JUST giving `-colored.png`? What is wrong with my string operation?

It needs to be `.../assets/images/icon-linkedin-colored.png`

Comment: Looks like your functions aren't returning what they should.

Comment: The last attempt (without echo and with `.`, which is correct, instead of `+`, which is JS, not PHP) should work if you change `the_sub_field('icon')` to `get_sub_field('icon')`. The difference is that `the_sub_field()` doesn't return the value, it outputs it (echoes it) while `get_sub_field()` returns it (which is what you want/need when you want to concatenate it)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay, that was it, but I don't know why it works now. Is it because "get_sub_field" "returns" a value or something?

Comment: I literally told you that in my comment :-) When concatenating strings, the functions needs to _return_ the value so it can be concatenated.

Comment: Test with `echo get_sub_field('icon');`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson your comment with the explanation wasnt published when I responded.