# SQL Update Statement throws SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php

When trying to update my database I get a *SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':summary, wentWell:wentWell, '* error. Would really appreciate some help since I have been trying to solve this problem for days now.

This is the code I use to update the database (journal.php):

```
    public function updateJournal($array) {
      $query = "UPDATE journal SET
                                  summary:summary, 
                                  wentWell:wentWell, 
                                  doBetter:doBetter, 
                                  ideas:ideas, 
                                  mood:mood, 
                                  motivation:motivation, 
                                  concentration:concentration, 
                                  tranquility:tranquility, 
                                  physical:physical WHERE id=:journalId";
      $stmt = $this -> connection -> prepare($query);
      $stmt -> execute();
    }
```

I use an array (updateJournal.php) to send the data to the updateJournal-Function (journal.php):

```
        $checkJournal -> updateJournal([
            "summary" => $summaryField,
            "wentWell" => $wentWellField,
            "doBetter" => $doBetterField,
            "ideas" => $ideasField,
            "mood" => $sliderValueMood,
            "motivation" => $sliderValueMotivation,
            "concentration" => $sliderValueConcentration,
            "tranquility" => $sliderValueTranquility,
            "physical" => $sliderValuePhysical,
            "journalId" => $journalId
        ]);
```

This is my Database:

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywHPO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first in your set query the syntax is wrong, you need to replace : with = .
Then no variable of the array is passed in your query you would need something like :

```
 $query = "UPDATE journal SET summary=".$array['summary'].",
                              wentWell=".$array['wentWell'].",...
```

I recommend you to look for [sql update doc](https://sql.sh/cours/update) and maybe some [php help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Comment: Thank you verry much! That helped a lot :) :)

Comment: no problem :), if you could validate my answer sir

Comment: This is not how you use prepared statements, though! You want to use bound parameters, not concatenate strings (they might contain SQL injection attacks).

Comment: true but one problem at a time

Answer (score 0):

The correct and safe way to do this is to use bound parameters like so (you were almost there):

```
    public function updateJournal($array) {
      $query = "UPDATE journal SET
                                  summary=:summary, 
                                  wentWell=:wentWell, 
                                  doBetter=:doBetter, 
                                  ideas=:ideas, 
                                  mood=:mood, 
                                  motivation=:motivation, 
                                  concentration=:concentration, 
                                  tranquility=:tranquility, 
                                  physical=:physical WHERE id=:journalId";
      $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute($array);
    }
```

You were only missing the equal signs in the assignements, which is what caused the syntax error.