# how to use variable in SQL query language in WordPress

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a DB table named 'affiliate_wp_coupons' where has 3 cols and they are;

1. coupon_id
2. affiliate_id
3. coupon_code

I have coupon_code which is coming from a variable, not static.
Now I wanted to query the associated affilaite_id value based on the coupon_code.

I am trying this code:

`` $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM affiliate_wp_coupons WHERE `coupon_code`= 'BS0PDDTTGU'"); ``

This code returns an Object with the matched col.

In the above code coupon_code value is static, how can I put a variable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$coupon_code = 'BS0PDDTTGU';
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM affiliate_wp_coupons WHERE `coupon_code`= %s", $coupon_code));
```

Answer (score 0):

There're multiple ways to concatenate/inserting variable into a string in PHP, ex:

```
$coupon_code = 'Windy';
$str = "Hello {$coupon_code}!"; // Hello Windy!
$str2 = "Hello $coupon_code!"; // Hello Windy!
$str3 = 'Hello '.$coupon_code.'!'; // Hello Windy!
```

personally I prefer `$str2`.

Then in your case you can replace your code something like:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM affiliate_wp_coupons WHERE `coupon_code`= '{$coupon_code}'");
```

**Note: don't forget to define `$coupon_code` before run query.**

- PHP reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php
- Related discussion: [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)