# Links convertation

Tags: php, optimization

I have made this links converting function that puts url in `<a></a>`tags:

```
function convert_links($text) {
    $text = explode(' ',$text);
    for($i=0;$i<count($text);$i++) {
        if(filter_var($text[$i], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
            $text[$i] = "<a href='".$text[$i]."' target='_blank'>".$text[$i]."</a>";
        else 
            $text[$i] = $text[$i];
    }
    return implode(' ',$text);
}
```

I am newbie in optimization, so I want to ask: can I make this function work better/ faster? I heard that array_filter is better choice in this situation, however I can not make it work. Thanks for your help!

Now I have made one more function with array_map. so, which one is better to use?

```
function convert_links($text) {
    $text = explode(' ', $text);
    function convert_link($val) {
        if(filter_var($val,FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
            return "<a href='".$val."' target='_blank'>".$val."</a>";
        else
            return $val;
    }
    $text = array_map('convert_link',$text);
    return implode(' ',$text);
}
```

Danielius

Comment: We help fix broken code. code optimization is basically offtopic.

Comment: oh, sorry about that then, should i remove my question? :) just have seen that tag "optimization" exists

Comment: Post your code with "array_filter", let's see why you cannot make  it work (click "edit" under your question, paste the code with array_filter, save the question).

Comment: `array_filter` does not seem like a good choice for this. `array_map` would make more sense.

Comment: Added! thanks, I will read about array_map :)

Comment: I have made new function now, sorry, about that array_filter. So, which one is better? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200214/how-can-i-measure-the-speed-of-code-written-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you could use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
function convert_links($text) {
    return preg_replace_callback("/\S+:\S+/", function ($match) {
        return filter_var($val = $match[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
            ? "<a href='$val' target='_blank'>$val</a>"
            : $val;
    }, $text);
}
```

Note that:

- Instead of an `if` with two `return` statements, you can have one `return` and the ternary operator `? ... :`.
- In double quoted strings you can just embed your variable; no need to concatenate with `.`.
- This function also works if URLs are separated by other white space than space (like newline, tab, ...).
- The regular expression requires the word to contain at least one `:` not at the start or end of the word. This will avoid the more expensive `filter_var` calls being made on "normal" words.

Comment: But I tried once and now know that `"$variable"` works slower than `".$variable."`, so i will change it :)

Comment: You're welcome. That is an interesting observation about `"$variable"`!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4871172/4402190 here I read such info :) Interesting stuff!