# MySQL load and delete on same PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to load data from MySQL and then display the results. I would like be able to delete the associated record as well.

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Reviews LIMIT 3";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<h1> " . $row["rTitle"]. " </h1>" . $row["rText"]. "<br> <a href="delete.php?id={$row['id']}">Delete</a>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$id = $_GET['rID'];
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Reviews WHERE id = {$id}");

$conn->close();

?>
```

I have a problem with this line:

```
echo "<h1> " . $row["rTitle"]. " </h1>" . $row["rText"]. "<br> <a href="delete.php?id={$row['id']}">Delete</a>";
```

Error: syntax error, unexpected 'delete' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Either change the double quote in `href=""` to single quote, or use single quote as your string wrapper

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes within your string.

Comment: The mysql_* interface that you've used for the deleting was removed from version 7 of PHP, you should now be using either the mysqli_* interface (MySQL Improved extension) or PDO. ***ALWAYS*** use prepared statements when plugging a variable into a query, no matter what the source of the data. Also instead of using the SELECT * just select only the fields that you're actually going to use

Comment: `echo "<h1> " . $row["rTitle"]. " </h1>" . $row["rText"]. "<br> <a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a>";` **OR**
`echo "<h1> {$row['rTitle']} </h1>{$row['rText']}<br> <a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']}>Delete</a>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<h1>'.$row["rTitle"].'</h1>'.$row["rText"].'<br><a href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks. This results in: syntax error, unexpected ''delete.php?id=".$row['' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I made changes try now and accept my answer if works.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<h1>'.$row["rTitle"].'</h1>'.$row["rText"].'<br> <a href="/delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
```

This will work and always try to use single `'` while framing html code bcz `'` is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871065/what-is-faster-in-php-single-or-double-quotes) than `"`.