# Using PHP variables inside HTML tags?

Tags: php, html

I am pretty new to php but I'm stuck on this problem... Say i wait to put a link to another site with a given parameter, how do I do it correclty?

This is what i have now:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $param = "test";

  echo "<a href="http://www.whatever.com/$param">Click Here</a>;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well, for starters, you might not wanna overuse echo, because (as is the problem in your case) you can very easily make mistakes on quotation marks.

This would fix your problem:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://www.whatever.com/$param\">Click Here</a>";
```

but you should really do this

```
<?php
  $param = "test";
?>
<a href="http://www.whatever.com/<?php echo $param; ?>">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll look more into seperating HTML and PHP I suppose :-)

Comment: first example is well for me but I guess for the second one, you need to echo the <a href... part...

Answer (score 15):

You can do it a number of ways, depending on the type of quotes you use:

- `echo "<a href='http://www.whatever.com/$param'>Click here</a>";`
- `echo "<a href='http://www.whatever.com/{$param}'>Click here</a>";`
- `echo '<a href="http://www.whatever.com/' . $param . '">Click here</a>';`
- `echo "<a href=\"http://www.whatever.com/$param\">Click here</a>";`

Double quotes allow for variables in the middle of the string, where as single quotes are string literals and, as such, interpret everything as a string of characters -- nothing more -- not even `\n` will be expanded to mean the new line character, it will just be the characters `\` and `n` in sequence.

You need to be careful about your use of whichever type of quoting you decide.  You can't use double quotes inside a double quoted string (as in your example) as you'll be ending the string early, which isn't what you want.  You can escape the inner double quotes, however, by adding a backslash.

On a separate note, you might need to be careful about [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks when printing unsafe variables (populated by the user) out to the browser.

Comment: The third one is the best option, because default in HTML are double quotes, and strings in single quotes are parsed faster in PHP.

Comment: @Midas There are 3 microseconds (over 1k iterations) in it apparently - http://www.phpbench.com which suggest that this is a micro-optimisation that totally isn't worth it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php

Answer (score 15):

There's a shorthand-type way to do this that I have been using recently.
This might need to be configured, but it should work in most mainline PHP installations.
If you're storing the link in a PHP variable, you can do it in the following manner based off the OP:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      $link = "http://www.google.com";
    ?>
    <a href="<?= $link ?>">Click here to go to Google.</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will evaluate the variable as a string, in essence shorthand for echo $link;

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using the short ' instead of ". If you do so, you wont longer have to escape the double quote (\").

In that case you would write

```
echo '<a href="http://www.whatever.com/'. $param .'">Click Here</a>';
```

But look onto nicolaas' answer "what you really should do" to learn how to produce cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a variable into a double quoted string like my first example, or you can use concantenation(the period) like in my second example:

`echo "<a href=\"http://www.whatever.com/$param\">Click Here</a>";`

`echo '<a href="http://www.whatever.com/' . $param . '">Click Here</a>';`

Notice that I escaped the double quotes inside my first example using a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

HI Jasper,

you can do this:

```
<?
sprintf("<a href=\"http://www.whatever.com/%s\">Click Here</a>", $param);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heredoc may be an option, see example 2 here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php