# Using php variables in included html

Tags: php, include, var

I'm looking for something much like the [Using PHP variables inside HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130596/using-php-variables-inside-html-tags) question, but a little different.

In my case, I'd like to use code ore like this:

```
$somevar = 'a test';

include("file.html");
```

and file.html would contain

```
<b>hello, this is {$somevar}</b>
```

The problem is that it just prints  **`hello, this is {$somevar}`**.

How can I make the HTML read the vars in the included file?

Comment: You need to echo it `<b>hello, this is <?php echo $somevar; ?></b>`

Comment: anything that's not within `<?php ?>` tag sets, or passed through `eval()` (bad idea, don't do it), is not run through the php parser.

Comment: @relentless You got it a bit backwards, see SamuelCook's answer

Comment: @Izkata - Yup, you're right. I wasn't paying enough attention. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<b>hello, this is {$somevar}</b>";
```

or

```
<b>hello, this is <?=$somevar?></b>
```

or

```
<b>hello, this is <?php echo $somevar; ?></b>
```

or

```
<b>hello, this is <?php print $somevar; ?></b>
```

Comment: im not sure. someone must not like it :/

Comment: someone must not like me very much.

Comment: Worth noting like @paquettg says, you have to change file.html to file.php

Comment: You don't need to change file extensions.

Comment: @nickb under default apache settings, you do

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with it.

Comment: No, PHP runs PHP. Apache invokes PHP for certain requests that match the configuration to be handled by PHP, but Apache doesn't control how PHP works. **You don't NEED Apache for PHP, nor do you need it to run PHP.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the variable defining program, in the other program wanting to access it.
Example:

```
   Say test.html has $somevar.
   in file.html you do,

   <?php
   include('test.html');
    echo "<b>hello, this is $somevar</b>"; 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include "stuff.php";
$somevar = "test";
?>

<html>
    <body><p><?php echo($somevar); ?></p></body>
</html>
```