# PHP use directories and links stored in variables

Tags: php, html

before asking this question i have been looking at these 2 posts but i can't seem to find the answer:

[Using PHP variables inside HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130596/using-php-variables-inside-html-tags)

[how do use php variable in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409625/how-do-use-php-variable-in-html)

I want to create a simple script that displays images with different links using values stored in variables but my script is not working.

```
<?php
    $array = array(
      "http://yahoo.com",  
      "http://bing.com",  
    );
    for ($val = 0; $val<2; $val++) {
      $b1 = "<a href='{$array[$val]}' target="_blank"><img src="./$val/1.jpg" alt="image here" title="Title"></a>";
      print $b1;
    }
?>
```

I apologize in advance, pretty sure it's a really dumb question but i really can't find a solution by myself...

Thanks!

Comment: need to escape the double quotes $b1 = "<a href='{$array[$val]}' target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"./$val/1.jpg\" alt=\"image here\" title=\"Title\"></a>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this

    <?php
$array = array(
          "http://yahoo.com",  
          "http://bing.com",  
        );
        for ($val = 0; $val<2; $val++) {
          $b1 = "<a href='{$array[$val]}' target='_blank'><img src='../$val/1.jpg' alt='image here' title='Title'></a>";
          print $b1;
        }
?>
```

Please replace double quote to sinlge qoute

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     $array = array(
          "http://yahoo.com",  
          "http://bing.com",  
        );
        for ($val = 0; $val";
          print $b1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to escape the double quotes **target=\"_blank\"**

```
 $b1 = "<a href='{$array[$val]}' target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"./$val/1.jpg\" alt=\"image here\" title=\"Title\"></a>";
```

OR

use single quotes inside the the double quotes like this

```
$b1 = "<a href='{$array[$val]}' target='_blank'><img src='./$val/1.jpg' alt='image here' title='Title'></a>";
```