# How do I download a file from a different URL by appending php variable

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to append a php variable to an html anchor tag to download a file from a remote URL without success. It opens the URL but doesn't download the file. I've tried all kinds of variations of the following code which is outside the php block:

```
<a href="http://example.org/"<?php echo "$isoname";?>><center><img src="images/uk_download.png" style="height:35px; width:144px;"  alt="download iso"> </center></a>
```

When I hover over the button it shows: xxx.org/f=example.iso

I'd appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: fyi, the `<center>` element is obsolete, use CSS instead

Comment: Check this answer that will help you in your question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130596/using-php-variables-inside-html-tags/6130648)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PHP variables inside HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130596/using-php-variables-inside-html-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, place your filename variable inside the quotes. Secondly, add the download attribute.

```
<a href="http://example.org/<?php echo $isoname;?>">
    <center>
    <img src="images/uk_download.png" style="height:35px; width:144px;"
         alt="download iso" download>
    </center>
</a>
```

Comment: That won't work. The download attribute is not supported for cross origin requests.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `download` attribute on the `a` tag.

Like so

```
<a href="http://example.org/<?php echo $isoname;?>">
    <center>
    <img src="images/uk_download.png" style="height:35px; width:144px;"
         alt="download iso" download="name_of_the_file.iso">
    </center>
</a>
```

Also included the PHP `echo` in the quotes.

Comment: An example might help here. please **edit** and show us `:-)`

Comment: That won't work. The download attribute is not supported for cross origin requests.