# incoporate php in html img tag

Tags: php, html

New to php and i have tried what I thought would work but it didnt work.
I have an image in my upload folder name 1002386235.png  the number 1002386235 is the user id and I would like to display a profile picture of the user with the help of php. With this  I can display the image. What I am trying to achieve is replace the 1002386235.png with something like $uid.png, $uid being a variable with the user id in it. I thought the following would work but it didnt

```html
<?php

$uid = "1002386235";

?>



<img src="upload/".$uid.".png">
```

Comment: Just a little search : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150238/php-variable-in-html-no-other-way-than-php-echo-var

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130596/using-php-variables-inside-html-tags

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PHP variables inside HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130596/using-php-variables-inside-html-tags)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the variable `$uid` within php tags and since your html is not inside php tags, the concatenation `dot` operators are not required. Also, you need to echo the variable inside your html.

Change this line:

```
<img src="upload/".$uid.".png">
```

To this:

```
<img src="upload/<?php echo $uid; ?>.png">
```

Comment: worked like a magic. Thanks