# What is the difference between double and single quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

I am new to PHP and in programming i have seen use of both "" and ' '.

What is the difference between "" and ' '?

And in declaring a link i have used the following ,but it does not seem to work there must be something wrong in quotation:

```
$abc_output .='<a href="abc.com">' Back to Main Menu'</a>';

echo $abc_output;
```

What might be the error here?

Comment: Your problem is that `Back to Main Menu` is not inside a string (as you can see from the syntax highlighter).

Answer (score 4):

You want to keep the text inside of your string:

```
$abc_output .='<a href="abc.com">Back to Main Menu</a>';
```

---

The difference between `'` and `"` is that you can embed variables inside of a double quoted string.

For example:

```
$name = 'John';
$sentence = "$name just left"; // John just left
```

If you were to use single quotes, then you'd have to concatenate:

```
$name = 'John';
$sentence = $name.' just left'; // John just left
```

---

PS: Don't forget that you always have to escape your quotes. The following 2 are the same:

```
$double = "I'm going out"; // I'm going out
$single = 'I\'m going out'; // I'm going out
```

Same applies the other way around:

```
$single = 'I said "Get out!!"'; // I said "Get out!!"
$double = "I said \"Get out!!\""; // I said "Get out!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes allow additional expressions, such as `"$variable \n"`, which single quotes don't. Compare:

```
$variable = 42;
echo "double: $variable,\n 43\n";
echo 'single: $variable,\n 43';
```

This outputs:

```
double: 42,
 43
single: $variable,\n 43
```

For more information, refer to the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

Text in double quotes are parsed.

For example:

```
$test = 'something';

print('This is $test');
print("This is $something");
```

would result in:

```
This is $test
This is something
```

If you don't need the string to be parsed you should use single quotes since it's better performance wise.

In your case you need to do:

```
$abc_output .='<a href="abc.com">Back to Main Menu</a>';
echo $abc_output;
```

Or you will get an error.

The Back to Main Menu wasn't in the string.

Comment: `use single quotes since it's better performance wise`. I always use single quotes, since I find them more convenient, but I never knew that it's better for performance. Do you have a source for that? And, does that also apply to Javascript?

Comment: @Joseph Silber: I'm sure if you use your Google skills :) you'll find out that I'm right. Basically PHP doesn't have to search the string for stuff to parse so it will be faster. I dunno bout JS and parsing strings.

Comment: maybe my google skills just suck, but I *did* search, found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php , read the comments to the answer, and wasn't impressed.

Comment: @Joseph Silber: Not impressed by the 30 times upvoted answer? Uff... tough crowd. :)

Comment: http://www.phpbench.com/ . Scroll down to `Quote types`.