# PHP echo href issue

Tags: php, href, session-cookies

I am trying to add a delete session option in my form, but I cannot get around the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /users/bfullilo/acme_dl_sessions.php on line 31

Here is my line 31

```
echo "<a href=\"acme_dl_sessions.php?delete_session=1\"> Not $_SESSION[\"email\"]?</a>";
```

I know that I'm not escaping everything I need to, but I've hit a wall.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slightly faster [to use single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php)

```
echo '<a href="acme_dl_sessions.php?delete_session=1"> Not ' . $_SESSION["email"] . '?</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mr.Pallazzo.  Your answer also removed the error in a more streamline manner.  I appreciate the link to an explanation of the speed difference as well.

Comment: No problem.. I like those puzzles :p

Answer (score 1):

change to either:

```
echo " Not $_SESSION[email]?";
```

or

```
echo " Not {$_SESSION['email']}?";
```

Comment: Thank you, @bfavaretto.  I changed the line to:     echo "<a href=\"acme_dl_sessions.php?delete_session=1\"> Not {$_SESSION["email"]}?</a>";  and I no longer get the error.