# PHP String literals and compiler optimization

Tags: php, optimization, php-opcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a performance benefit single quote vs double quote in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php)

I am wondering if PHP code takes a performance hit when using `"`s when defining strings *containing no variables*, compared to `'` where the extra parsing is not performed.

For example, PHP will try to parse variables inside strings defined by `"` but not `'`.

```
$myString = "Greetings earthlings!";
echo '$myString'; //literally outputs the string '$myString'
echo "$myString"; //literally outputs the string "Greetings earthlings"
```

So my question is, all this time I've been writing code like this:

```
echo "Greetings earthlings";
```

Have I been wasting cycles? Or is PHP smart/optimized enough to know I *really* meant:

```
echo 'Greetings earthlings';
```

?

Comment: yes, but its so tiny, its not really a consideration. there's a benchmark of the difference somewhere on the web. but you could do your own in less than a minute. http://www.phpbench.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of work with [VLD](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld) tells me that both programs compile to identical bytecode (using PHP 5.3):

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  >   ECHO                                                     'Hello+world'
   3     1    > RETURN                                                   1
```

Conclusion: There's absolutely no difference in modern versions of PHP. None whatsoever. Use whatever feels best to you.

---

There is, however, a difference between `echo "Hello $world"`:

```
compiled vars:  !0 = $world
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0  >   ADD_STRING                                       ~0      'Hello+'
         1      ADD_VAR                                          ~0      ~0, !0
         2      ECHO                                                     ~0
         3    > RETURN                                                   null
```

And `echo "Hello " . $world`:

```
compiled vars:  !0 = $world
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0  >   CONCAT                                           ~0      'Hello+', !0
         1      ECHO                                                     ~0
         2    > RETURN                                                   null
```

I'd hesitate to call that significant, though. The actual real-world difference in performance is, in all probability, trivial.

Comment: +1 QED, this answer should be merged with the original duplicate.. very nice

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run benchmarks to see. I did for PHP 4 and discovered that doing string concatenation was much faster (an order of magnitude? I don't remember exactly) than embedded variables. By comparison, plain strings in double quotes were only very slightly faster than single quotes.

But that was for PHP *4*. I ran the same tests later for PHP *5* and the difference in performance is pretty much negligible.