# php associative array of strings only returns first word

Tags: php, associative-array

In this associative array I have only strings of text including spaces.  When I access an element of the array to print the text I only get the first word.  How do I retrieve all the text with the spaces?

```
    $feast_description = array('Mother_of_God' => 'Recognition of the Blessed Virgin Mary as the Mother of Jesus who is the Son of God and is God Himself.',
    'Epiphany' => 'Recognition of Jesus by the Magi as one sent by God.',
    'Baptism_of the Lord' => 'Jesus asks of John the Baptist that he baptize Him in the Jordan river. This act was to teach us of the necessity of baptism to be washed clean of our corruption for admittance among God\'s children and for salvation. This day God also revealed Jesus to be His Son.',
    'Presentation_of_the_Lord' => 'Jesus as first born of the Holy Family is presented at temple and consecrated to God.',
    'Ash_Wednesday' => 'Beginning of Lent the season of penance to make up for our sins and draw nearer to God in preparation for Easter.',
    'Holy_Thursday' => 'First feast of the Easter Triduum. We commemorate the Last Supper when Jesus began the Sacrament of the Eucharist.  On that day He also gave an example of service and of humility by washing the feet of His disciples.','Good_Friday' => 'Day of the Passion of Jesus when He was crucified and died to offer His life in reparation for our sins.  By giving up His earthly life as a sacrifice to God the Father, He earned for us divine life, eternal life with the Father in Heaven.',
    'Holy_Saturday' => 'A day of waiting between Good Friday and the Resurrection of the Lord on Easter Sunday morning.  On the vigil of Easter the Church celebrates a special liturgy which traces the history of salvation.',
    'Easter' => 'Jesus who was crucified three days earlier, went among the dead, descended into hell and returned to life victorious over death.  He won that victory for all mankind.  Upon the Resurrection of Jesus is founded the hope of every Christian that we too will conquer death.',
    'Ascension' => 'Jesus returns to the Father, having fulfilled His mission on earth, to teach us of the Father\'s love, show us His commands, and teach us the way back to Him.  He did not linger in His earthly life to be our intercessor and our advocate at the right hand of the Father. By ascending to the Father Jesus secures our place with Him.  He returns to the Father, taking up with Him all of humanity and forever defeats the one who constantly seeks to separate us from our God.',
    'Pentecost' => 'Jesus promised that He would not leave us by ourselves as He returns to the Father.  He promised to send a paraclete, a helper, an advocate.  He does on Pentecost, He sends the Holy Spirit, to be with us in this new manner and to remain with us until the end of time.',
);
```

This array element

```
$feast_description['Mother_of_God']
```

only returns the word `Recognition`, the first word in the string.

I output the string in the `title` of an `<a>` tag with an echo statement like this.

```
echo ' '.$litweek.' week <a title='.$feast_description['Mother_of_God'].'>'.$litsea.'</a>&nbsp;&#8226;';
```

What is the right way to get all the text?

Comment: Do you get a different result if you put the value in double quotes? `'Mother_of_God' => "Recognition of the Blessed Virgin..."` ?

Comment: Your array definition is correct. How exactly are you "returning" from the array?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to output this array value?

Comment: This is not related to your question, but you can use spaces in array keys like `Mother of God`.

Comment: Yes, spaces in array keys are not a problem.

Comment: Seems fine: http://codepad.org/jqwrKEoI

Comment: Best to use single quotes unless including variables within the quotes.  See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php

Comment: Doesn't make a difference if I put double quotes.  I output the string in the `title` of an `<a>` tag with an echo statement like this.  ` echo ' '.$litweek.' week <a title='.$feast_description['Mother_of_God'].'>'.$litsea.'</a>&nbsp;&#8226;';` @joeshmo Thanks for the tip about having spaces in the keys.

Comment: @j08691  It does work.  I needed quotes around the string in my echo statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing quotes around the array element. HTML had to be specified as

```
echo ' '.$litweek.' week <a title="'.$feast_description['Mother_of_God'].'">'.$litsea.'</a>&nbsp;&#8226;';
```

with double quotes around $feast_description.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to lose the dot before the brackets, should be like:

```
$feast_description['Mother_of_God']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($feast_description as $name => $text) {
    echo $name . " : " . $text . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echo you might want to try using print format and pass in the values.  It makes it easier to write the html and keep the value assignments tidy.

```
printf(' %s week <a title="%s">%s</a>&nbsp;&#8226;', 
    $litweek, $feast_description['Mother_of_God'], $litsea);
```