# Questions Related To Implode Function PHP

Tags: php, implode

I am exploding an array appending it and then I am imploding the array back. Everything works fine but I got a small doubt. Please take the example below.

```
$x = "123,456,789"
explode (' ', $x);
$x[] = "987";
implode (',', $x);
```

The output looks like the following :

```
,123,456,789,987
```

The problem is that the comma appears before the values. I want them to appear after just like the following

```
123,456,789,987,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x = '123,456,789'; // use ' instead " (just for performance)
$x = explode (',', $x);
$x[] = '987';
$y = implode (',', $x);

echo $y . ','; // add trailing comma (what nickb said)

// output: 
123,456,789,987,
```

---

About the **single vs double quotes** issue please refers to [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and [Is there a performance benefit single quote vs double quote in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php)

Comment: The performance difference between using single or double quotes for a string is beyond negligible.

Comment: @nickb Don't understand. So advice to a newbie to distinguish between correct uses of Single and Double quotes is not right any more? Please explain.

Comment: There's realistically no performance benefit in switching between the two, nor is it "incorrect" to use double quotes when you don't have variables being substituted into the string.

Comment: @nickb I do not agree with you but whatever. When I do  not need expand variables or some special characters I always use single quotes. For other readers interested in this issue just refers to [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Where on that page does it say "using single quotes will yield better performance over double quotes"?

Answer (score 3):

You're exploding on a blank space instead of a comma:

```
explode (' ', $x);
```

should be

```
explode (',', $x);
```

Comment: And you'll also have to tack on an additional comma at the end to match the desired output

Comment: even then while imploding i get the same output. I need that other output