# how to apply bgcolor in table using echo command

Tags: php, html

I want to apply background colour to a table. I have written table using echo command , but am confused about how to apply bgcolor can any one guide me..

```
print("<table align='center' width='50%' border=1> ");
echo "<TR><TD> Sr.No </td>";
echo "<td  width=\"16%\" bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"> delete</td>";
echo "<Td> File Name </td> ";
echo "<td> Share It </td>";
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: instead of bgcolor you should use CSS's background-color property. =o)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<tr><td> Sr.No</td>';
echo '<td width="16%" bgcolor="' . $colorVariable .  '"> delete</td>';
echo '<td> File Name </td>';
echo '<td> Share It</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 2):

The "'s are colliding. You need to escape the character, like below.

```
echo"<td  width=\"16%\" bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"> delete</td>";
```

Comment: Did it work? If it did, you should click the check box below the number of votes.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo '<td  width="16%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> delete</td>';
```

**PHP double quote and single quote**

```
$some="Oh god";

echo "My answer is $some ";

//result is: My answer is Oh god
```

In the above, using double quotes, the variable $someis evaluated within the quotes and the result isn't what is expected: the variable is evaluated to Oh god. Variables, but not functions or constants, are evaluated even when enclosed in double quotes.

```
echo 'My answer is $some';

//result is: My answer is $some.
```

When single quotes are used, as above, the variable isn't evaluated and is printed on the screen literally as $some.

---

**good read**

[**Is there a performance benefit single quote vs double quote in php?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php)