# how can i optimize mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

i use this query for fetching data from database

how can i optimize and use best code for this connection?

```
connect();
$games_sql = mysql_query("SELECT gameid,mizbanid,mihmanid,score1,score2,gamedavar,gamestadium,now FROM games WHERE gameweek='$site_week' ORDER BY now ASC LIMIT 9");
for( $i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows( $games_sql ); $i++ ) {
    $gameid = @mysql_result( $games_sql, $i, 0);
    $mizbanid = @mysql_result( $games_sql, $i, 1 );
    $mihmanid = @mysql_result( $games_sql, $i, 2);
    $score1 = @mysql_result( $games_sql, $i, 3);
    $score2 = @mysql_result( $games_sql, $i, 4);
    $gamedavar = @mysql_result( $games_sql, $i, 5);
    $gamestadium = @mysql_result( $games_sql, $i, 6);
    $now = @mysql_result( $games_sql, $i, 7);
    $gametimeanddate = jdate("l d M y ساعت G:i", $now);
    $gamedate = jdate("l d M y", $now);
    $gametime = jdate("G:i", $now);


`connect()` function include `mysql_connect` & `mysql_select_db`
```

how can i optimize this code for low `user_connection` to database and high speed ?

Comment: whoa dont do this .. i mean dont using @ to ignoe erroris not a good option

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: please suggest new code for replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you query the database once to catch all information?
Take a look at this:

```
connect();
$sql = 'SELECT 
    gameid,
    mizbanid,
    mihmanid,
    score1,
    score2,
    gamedavar,
    gamestadium,
    now
FROM games
WHERE gameweek = ' . $site_week . '
ORDER BY now ASC
    LIMIT 9';
$query = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    while($Result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) { //loop trough results

        print_r($Result); //prints the results.
        echo $Result->gameid; //this is how you echo the data
}
}
```

Be aware that the mysql_query function is deprecated and needs to be replaced by mysqli :) .

Comment: you use mysql_fetch_object
what is reason for dont use : 
mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_array?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use cache and memcache as an optimizing solution. You can cache your queries and for the rest requests you can pop if from cache

Comment: i am begginer
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Well There is always a mile to go.. You can do optimization in several ways, with php code as well as with your Query, however you shouldn't use things that are about to extinct

```
Warning
```

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

```
mysqli_stmt_num_rows()
PDOStatement::rowCount()
```

If you just want to count the rows you should better use:-

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable`

And you should not use single quotes That has [benefit over double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php)

and As mentioned by NullPointer, you should not [use @ to suppress error message](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.

Comment: And for php performance you may read this one http://phplens.com/lens/php-book/optimizing-debugging-php.php And this one https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php